# Creating a polling bot

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests

dados = {"action": "polls",
         "view":"process",
         "poll_id":"2",
         "poll_2":"6",
          "poll_2_nonce":"e29cc82a53"}

url = "http://soulegal.byethost7.com/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

requests.post(url, data=dados)
```

The site URL is : http://soulegal.byethost7.com/wp/2016/07/28/pesquisa-eu-sou-legal

The wordpress plugin is WP-Polls.

The site is mine (I’m not testing in third part page )
Still it does not work. I wonder what ‘s going on?
I can vote manually but not with the code !

Comment: I am not a wordpress expert, but I'm not sure you can go past `wp/wp-admin/` without authentication.

Comment: It would be useful to see the php code that you are trying to access...

Comment: You dont need authentication to vote.

Comment: How do you know the correct JSON to pass to the URL?

Comment: I looked it up using web developer tool of firefox (network option).

Comment: The nonce is going top be generated each time you load the page but your biggest issue is you need to js enabled to fetch the source, it is trivial to parse the values you need from the page but getting the source is probably going to need something like selenium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to do a few things:

1. You need to use a `requests.Session` instance so it can track cookies for you, including the cookie that Wordpress uses to allow you to vote from your poll page (which you have to make a get request to first).
2. You need to get the nonce value dynamically
3. To vote repeatedly, you need to get rid of the voted cookie after submission.

Comment: I think the nonce does not change. My plugin configuration is Logging Method -> Poll Logging Method: Do not log.

Comment: When I visited your poll, I received a different nonce, so I doubt that it does not change. Were it to be static, there would be no reason to have a nonce.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress creates an IP/PC/Mac address and sever side keys (similiar to the PHP session id) which is used for loading. As well you might want to check what cookies are going back and forth between your browser and the voting poll page.

Comment: I dont understand why I can vote many times manually but not automatically.